# mongodb design database for high volume of writing

Tags: mongodb, nosql, facebook-insights

I have an issue with designing a database in mongo db.

So in general, the system will continuously gather insight user data (e.g. likes, retweets, views) from different social websites apis (twitter api , instagram api , fb api) with with different rate of each channel. While also saving each insight every hour as historical data . These current real time insights should be viewed by users in the website. 
Should I save the insight data in cache and the historical insight data in document ?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want from us, design it for you?

Comment: System design is a difficult job.  "fastest writes" and "actually queryable data shape" often conflict with each other. You most likely will have to find some form of middle ground between the two.

Comment: At least, start from writing down all the queries that you'll want to make. What data shape(s) would enable the queries? Then look into ways of producing that data shape.

Comment: Thank you Sergio , can you give me article or guide to get started as I am so much confused how design the collections.

Comment: I wish I could give you some articles or tutorials, but nothing pops into memory. In my case it was mostly trial and error. Make a thing, find out why it's not working as I expected, fix, repeat until perfection.

Comment: Thank you Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the expected write rate and query rate? 
What rate will the dataset grow at? These are key questions that will determine the size and topology of your MongoDB Cluster. If your write rate does not exceed the write capacity of a single node then you should be able to host your data on a single [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/). However, this assumes that your data set is not large (>1TB). At that size recovery from a single node failure can be time-consuming (it will not cause an outage but the longer a single node is down the higher the risk of a second node failing).

In both cases (write capacity exceeds a single node or dataset is larger than 1TB) the rough guidance is that this is the time to consider a `[sharded cluster][2]`. Design of a sharded cluster is beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Really Thank you Joe.

Comment: In case I design the dataset for single node replica set. Is it will be needed to revamp the design of collections  in order to make it sharded cluster design ?